# How to let to know parent that their child was deleted?

Tags: java, database, jpa, one-to-many, cascading-deletes

> Hi i'm making application for recipe. One user could have many recipes and then he can delete his recipe. I store date in data base. User have a list of recipes in one of the field in db.I dont know what to do to delete a recipe on that list. I delete a recipe in db but is still on list in user field so we still can reach that recipe. I use JpaResporitory .There i give a part of my code. Could you help me please ?

```
public ResponseEntity<String> deleteRecipeById(long id, @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails details) {//toDo
   Recipe currentRecipe = getRecipeById(id);
   User currentUser = userRepository.findByEmail(details.getUsername())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    if(currentRecipe.getUser().equals(currentUser) ){
        currentUser.deleteFromUserList(currentRecipe);
        recipeRepository.delete(currentRecipe);
        // AND WHAT HERE ?
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).build();
```

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Recipe {
...
  @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",  nullable = false)
    private User user;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class User {
...
   @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true ,  fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @ToString.Exclude
    @Column(name = "recipes")
    private List<Recipe> recipes = new ArrayList<>();
} THERE IS THAT LIST THAT I CAN'T CHANGE AND  NEED THIS TO DELETE RECIPE
```

there is how i save recipe

```
  public Long create(Recipe recipe, UserDetails details) {
        User currentUser = userRepository.findByEmail(details.getUsername())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
        recipe.setUser(currentUser);
        currentUser.getRecipes()
                .add(recipe);
        userRepository.save(currentUser);
        return userRepository.findByEmail(details.getUsername())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"))
                .getRecipes()
                .get(userRepository.findByEmail(details.getUsername())
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"))
                        .getRecipes()
                        .size() - 1)
                .getId();
    }
```

I tried googling that i read article about jpa but i still dont know what i have to do

Comment: What do you do in `deleteFromUserList`?

Comment: Where exactly you see that `receipe` is not deleted from user

Comment: public void deleteFromUserList(Recipe recipe){
        recipes.remove(recipe);
    }

Comment: @GetMapping("/api/recipe/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Recipe> getRecipes(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(recipeService.getRecipeById(id));
    }

public Recipe getRecipeById(Long id) {
        return recipeRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(RecipeNotFoundException::new);
    }

that's still find recipe in db

Comment: So what you did is that you called `deleteRecipeById` API, then you called `getRecipes` API and it still return you the recipe you think it should have been deleted when called`deleteRecipeById` ?

Comment: also do you use a Transaction?

Comment: did you make sure it was deleted from DB?

Comment: no i don't use tansaction , 
its deleted from data baze but field user don't know it and he has saved recipe on list

Comment: where do you see that user still has the recipe even after deleting it?

Comment: /api/recipe/{id} still returns  recipe with that id

Comment: Can you show `recipeService.getRecipeById` code

Comment: also when you delete, you don't actualy do hard delete you just mark the record as deleted correct?

Comment: public Recipe getRecipeById(Long id) { return recipeRepository.findById(id) .orElseThrow(RecipeNotFoundException::new); }

Comment: i think i have to do hard delete in db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the real issue given info you posted, is that you remove `recipe` from `user` but you don't save `user` after

You either do:

1- Call `userRepository.save(currentUser)`, after removing `recipe` from user

OR better >

2- Annotate `deleteRecipeById` with `@Transactional` and it will do the job

If you wonder how no.2 will do the job, it is because when you load entity from DB talking `user` here, the entity becomes in a Managed state meaning that if you do any updates to that entity like `recipes.remove(recipe);`
then this managed entity `user` becomes eligible for updates, if you are in an opened transaction and that transaction gets committed [meaning function annotated with `@Transactional` comes to end] that managed entity `user` updates will be written to DB since transaction is committed, which will issue update SQL query to remove that `receipe` from user

*TIP, BTW, you can not use write operation against DB without a transaction scope, the fact you deleted `recipe` when you called
`recipeRepository.delete(currentRecipe);`
it is because Spring Repositories are annotated with `@Transactional` by default and that is why solution no 2 is better since now you would use only one transaction for both operations instead of the solution no 1 that would issue 2 transactions